# What does the typescript or angular syntax methondName(): void{ } mean? (code within)

Tags: angular, typescript, methods, angular6, void

From the Angular Tour Of Heroes tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

The code :

```
getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
}
```

What does this syntax of declaring a method mean?

Comment: Which part of it do you not understand, specifically? Have you read e.g. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html?

Comment: This is just a method that doesn't return anything (`void`) and sets a property (`this.heroes`) to whatever the `this.heroService.getHeroes()` function returns

Comment: 6 downvotes? I don't understand SO folks. This is a site to ask questions right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getHeroes** *is the name of the method*

**: void** *which returns void (nothing)*

**{** *beginning of the method body*

**this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();** *the return value of the method-call 'getHeroes' (from the heroService) gets assigned to the local variable 'heroes'*

**}** *end of the method body*

Comment: Thank you.
So if a method does not return anything does that mean it *must* be declared void using the " : void " ?

Comment: No. the `: void` part is optional like all typings are in typescript. But it is a good practice to do so because it will help you in places where you use your mehtod. For instance if you, in another place, call this method and try to assign the return value (which does not exist) to a variable, your editor will warn you about it.